# Popup documentation from Android Studio 3.0 rc2

Tags: android-studio, popup, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.0 rc2 keeps showing the pop-up documentation window...very annoying.  Does anyone else have the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to File > Settings or do Ctrl+Alt+S
- Under Editor > General
- Uncheck Show quick documentation on mouse move